# GIMP Close edited image without asking for confirmation

Tags: linux, gui, gimp, exit

I was able to disable the confirmation dialog when closing an image. I successfully did so at a previous version of GIMP but apparently an update to GIMP 2.8.14 (on Arch Linux) disabled it and I can't find the setting anywhere.

[image]

Please help me find the setting or the changeset which removed the functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, at least in 2.8.16 you can quickly shut down the confirmation dialog with Ctrl-d. So you can quickly close an image with Ctrl-w + Ctrl-d.

Comment: I got accustomed to pressing CTRL+D quickly now. Not a solution but a good workaround.

Comment: Okay, all things considered this is a solution for me by now. :D

Answer (score 3):

One of the changes in 2.8.14 with respect to 2.8.10 is:
"- Remove the option to disable the warning when closing a modified image"

So the "solution" is to install 2.8.10, or even 2.8.8 which seems less prone to crash.

Comment: Why was this removed, and can we add a feature request to get it back?